# Find out public ip address of the EC2 server

Tags: amazon-ec2

i would like to find the public IP address of my EC2 instance from within the server itself.I know it is possible using ec2-describe-instances.
But i want to do it assuming ec2-api-tools are not installed.

Is there a way to find that out?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/2009-04-04/meta-data/public-ipv4
```

Also,

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/2009-04-04/meta-data/
```

to get a list of other metadata you can get.

Comment: Nice! Fuller reference: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AESDG-chapter-instancedata.html

Comment: It also works with this: `curl http://instance-data/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4`

Answer (score 6):

There's a quick way to do it from the console on any server

With curl:

```
$ curl wgetip.com
```

With wget:

```
$ wget wgetip.com
```

Answer (score 3):

As a matter of course, I now assign an Elastic IP to all new permanent (anything longer than a day) EC2 instances.  This makes everything so much easier.

Answer (score 2):

Can't you just nslookup it?