# How to find out an ec2 instance's private and public IP via aws cli?

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cli

Answers I found so far (e.g. [Find out public ip address of the EC2 server](https://serverfault.com/questions/201719/find-out-public-ip-address-of-the-ec2-server)) suggest using `wget` or `curl` to reach the server.

They are not useful for me because my ec2 instances are not reachable from the internet directly.

I have tried

```
aws ec2 --profile prod describe-instances --filters Name=instance-id,Values=i-00914683ababcba7eb1
```

But there are no IPs in the returned JSON result.

Which `aws` CLI command I can use to retrieve this info?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Generally you can do it with --query filter.

If you need the private IP address only:

```
aws --region YOUR-AWS-REGION \
ec2 describe-instances \
--filters \
"Name=instance-state-name,Values=running" \
"Name=instance-id,Values=i-00914683ababcba7eb1" \
--query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[PrivateIpAddress]' \
--output text
```

If you need the public ip address only:

```
aws --region YOUR-AWS-REGION \
ec2 describe-instances \
--filters \
"Name=instance-state-name,Values=running" \
"Name=instance-id,Values=i-00914683ababcba7eb1" \
--query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[PublicIpAddress]' \
--output text
```

Or you can have both:

```
aws --region YOUR-AWS-REGION \
ec2 describe-instances \
--filters \
"Name=instance-state-name,Values=running" \
"Name=instance-id,Values=i-00914683ababcba7eb1" \
--query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[PrivateIpAddress, PublicIpAddress]' \
--output text
```

Of course you can have the output in json format too. Just change `--output text` to `--output json`

[More information about --query filters.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-output.html)

Comment: --query should be written with double quote
`aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=tag:Name,Values=Bastion" --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].[PublicIpAddress]" --output text`

Answer (score 1):

Search using tag name

aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=tag:Name,Values=*myinstance*" --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].{Instance:InstanceId,OS:PlatformDetails,Status:State,PrivateIpAddress:PrivateIpAddress,PublicIpAddress:PublicIpAddress,Tags:Tags}'

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I can do this

```
aws ec2 --profile prod describe-instances \
--filters Name=instance-id,Values=i-0f47d09e1d9659981 \
| jq ".Reservations[0].Instances[0].NetworkInterfaces[0].PrivateIpAddress"
```

and it will return

```
10.0.9.7
```

My command in the question failed because, coincidentally, that instance was being shut down. So there was no `NetworkInterfaces` section in the result.